# Jenkins fails to connect to node, no known hosts file was found

Tags: tomcat, jenkins

been banging my head against the wall for over a day now, so maybe someone can point me in the right direction.

---

Issue: When Jenkins tries to connect to a node, it fails citing:

```
No Known Hosts file was found at /usr/share/tomcat/.ssh/known_hosts
```

---

Details:

- Created a vanilla instance of Jenkins running on tomcat with nginx as the front end. This is within virtualbox.
- JENKINS_HOME=*/usr/share/tomcat/webapps/jenkins/.jenkins*, set by defining within */etc/sysconfig/tomcat*
- Node root directory is set as */home/jenkins*
- Node is a basic centos/nginx server on virtualbox as well.

---

Troubleshooting:

- (failed) Set selinux to Permissive (for testing)
- (failed) Created a symlink */usr/share/tomcat/.ssh -> /home/jenkins/.ssh*
- (failed) temporarily set all permissions to 777 on symlink, .ssh dir, and known_hosts file (just for testing)
- (resolved with) Created the file */usr/share/tomcat/.ssh/known_hosts*.  Would prefer to use a symlink though.

---

Questions:

1. What else could be preventing tomcat/jenkins from following the symlink and successfully reading known_hosts?
2. Why is tomcat/jenkins looking */usr/share/tomcat* instead of the Remote root directory of */home/jenkins*?

thanks!

Comment: So with the symlink still in place, if I change the node Host Key Verification Strategy to: Manually trusted key Verification Strategy, then the connection works fine.
I thought this method was supposed to prompt you to trust the SSH Key?  If known_hosts is not accessible as the previous error message claims, shouldn't this fail as well?

Comment: rebuilt jenkins from scratch and im running into the same issue when adding nodes.  Jenkins is looking for a Known Host file entry at /usr/share/tomcat/.ssh/known_hosts

How can I change this and why isn't jenkins creating the directory and known_hosts file on its own?

Comment: alright, so i went a step further and allowed the tomcat user a shell and then logged in.  with the symlink in place, /usr/share/tomcat/.ssh -> /home/jenkins/.ssh, I made sure that i could cat /usr/share/tomcat/.ssh/known_hosts and see the contents.
However, jenkins continues to complain that "No Known Hosts file was found at /usr/share/tomcat/.ssh/known_hosts"
im baffled.

Comment: Went back to using "manually trusted key verification strategy".   After implementing the symlink and making sure permissions were set appropriately, I changed the Host Key Verification Strategy from "Known hosts file verification strategy" to "Manually trusted key Verification Strategy".

I also added the SSH key to the known_hosts file by using:
"sudo ssh-keyscan -H <slave node> | sudo tee -a ./known_hosts"

Still feel like this is a hack.